# ckeditor set custom skinpath

Tags: get, ckeditor, loading, skin

I have a problem with the CKEDITOR. I installed it with bower and changed the basepath. So CKEDITOR works.
My problem now is to laod a custom skin, because i download it also with bower.

This is the code:

```
<textarea id="editor-<?= $block_count ?>" name="block[<?= $block_count ?>][text][]" rows="10" cols="80" class="form-control"></textarea>
    <script>
      CKEDITOR.replace('editor-<?= $block_count ?>',{
        customConfig: '../../dist/scripts/ckeditor.js',
        skin: 'office2013'
      });
    </script>
```

But if it want to laod the skin i get this error message:

```
ckeditor.js:76 GET     
htttp://myurl.com/src/bower_components/ckeditor/skins/office2013/editor.css?t=G87D
```

Can i define a skinpath to load it from teh bower path like:

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor-<?= $block_count ?>',{
    customConfig: '../../dist/scripts/ckeditor.js',
    skinpath: 'src/bower_componnts/ckeditor-office2013-skin/office2013/',
    skin: 'office2013'
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. [Check the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-skin). Quoting docs:

> It is possible to install skins outside the default skin folder in the editor installation. In that case, the absolute URL path to that folder should be provided, separated by a comma ('skin_name,skin_path').

```
config.skin = 'moono';

config.skin = 'myskin,/customstuff/myskin/';
```

So, something similar should do the trick:

```
skin: 'office2013,/src/bower_components/ckeditor-office2013-skin/office2013/'
```

Comment: There is a slightly different syntax for plugins, but yes it's also doable: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.resourceManager-method-addExternal

`CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal( 'sample', '/myplugins/sample/' );`. Note: this command only "registers" the external path to a plugin. In order to use the plugin in CKEditor instance it has to be also turned on via `config.extraPlugins` (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraPlugins)